# Error Installing psycopg2 on Amazon Linux

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, python-3.x, emr

When installing `psycopg2` on Amazon Linux using this command: `sudo pip-3.4 install psycopg2` I get this output:

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.7 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=90218 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I. -I/usr/include/pgsql92 -I/usr/include/pgsql92/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    In file included from ./psycopg/replication_cursor.h:30:0,
                     from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:32:
    ./psycopg/libpq_support.h:31:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘XLogRecPtr’
     typedef unsigned PG_INT64_TYPE XLogRecPtr;
                                    ^
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:32:0:
    ./psycopg/replication_cursor.h:47:5: error: unknown type name ‘XLogRecPtr’
         XLogRecPtr  write_lsn;        /* LSNs for replication feedback messages */
         ^
    ./psycopg/replication_cursor.h:48:5: error: unknown type name ‘XLogRecPtr’
         XLogRecPtr  flush_lsn;
         ^
    ./psycopg/replication_cursor.h:49:5: error: unknown type name ‘XLogRecPtr’
         XLogRecPtr  apply_lsn;
         ^
    In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:33:0:
    ./psycopg/replication_message.h:46:5: error: unknown type name ‘XLogRecPtr’
         XLogRecPtr  data_start;
         ^
    ./psycopg/replication_message.h:47:5: error: unknown type name ‘XLogRecPtr’
         XLogRecPtr  wal_end;
         ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I already have `gcc`, `postgresql-devel`, `postgresql-libs`, and `python34-devel` installed. Am I missing a package or setting?

Edit: This is on an EMR node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem with EMR, I tried below

```
sudo yum -y install gcc python-setuptools python-devel postgresql-devel
sudo /usr/bin/pip install --upgrade pip 
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install psycopg2
```

It works when I'm running it on EMR but doesn't work when EMR is spin up from Pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading pip fixed the problem. Unfortunately, it causes other problems with some pip versioning, but that should work for now. I'm also working on EMR so maybe that's related to the problem.

Comment: I was able to get psycopg2 installed with only `yum install gcc postgresql-devel`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install psycopg2 for python3 you must install python3-devel as well.

To find the correct package
`yum search python3 | grep devel`

In my case it was python36-devel so I did
`sudo yum install python36-devel`

And then I could install psycopg2 for my python3 virtualenvironment on the machine

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for psycopg2 for python3 in amazon linux, this is what worked for me:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc postgresql-devel
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python36
sudo pip-3.6 install -U psycopg2
```